# When should I use "see" vs. "refer"?

Tags: word-choice, technical

I have this question on using *see* and *refer* in technical documentation especially for cross-references information.

I use *see* when mentioning another section in the same document, for example, *for more information on xyz, see section abc on page nn-mm*.

I use *refer* when asking the reader to see an external document or any appendices, for example, *for more information on xyz, refer to the ABC Guide* or *for more information, refer to Appendix A*.

My colleagues and I have a disagreement with this logic. They seem to prefer *see* for everything. As a cross-reference is more like a footnote and also acts like a footnote.

Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 4):

Both are actually correct. The OED has:

> The imperative see is used in books to refer to a passage in the same or *some other work* in which information will be found.

for see and:

> To direct the attention of (a person) to a source of information (in earlier use chiefly a book).

for refer.

So it's really just a matter of preference.

Comment: This is what I find on the NOAD too.

Answer (score 0):

As a Technical Author:

- If the content I am directing the reader to is located within the same document, I use:

"SEE: '*Section heading*' "

- If the content is found in another place / document (Outside of the current document...), then I use:

"Refer: , i.e. [www.OED.co.uk](http://www.OED.co.uk) or '*Another Document about stuff that mentions this thing.*' "